# How to effectively manage projects and their contacts within CiviCRM?

Tags: contacts, groups, civicampaign

Good morning,

in our organisation, we frequently have to deal with the following scenario, a practical solution to which with CiviCRM I have so far not been able to establish. I would greatly appreciate insights on how to do this:

Scenario: Our organisation has a large number of diverse contacts from journalists to banks to volunteers. A selection of these regularly needs to be contacted within the scope of a project running for, say, 6 months. The contacts are made individually, not through mass mailings, and contact progress needs to be recorded individually, too. The relevant co-worker needs to be able to pull up a complete list of contacts pertaining to a certain project, quickly grasp the status of each contact and act on new opportunities, challenges, or delays.

Now, I have tried to use CiviCampaign to pull individual selections of contacts out of our overall pool. However, as I cannot track individual contact progress in CiviCampaign (but only mass mailings) this does not seem practical.

I have further tried to separate contact groups by "Groups" or tags and then tried to use a report to get an overview of these. However, as reports are not meant to be interactive, I cannot jump into a contact, work on it and return to the overview in the report easily.

Can somebody advise if this is practically feasible without additional programming?

Thanks!
Bijan

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use CiviCase to simulate a project? You can then add relevant case roles to the case type 'Project' and retrieve all them as relationships with a specific case_id. This would be a good way to get all contacts relevant to a project?
We have used a similar approach with one of our customers succesfully (although we added some stuff too as their requirements were more complicated).

Comment: Erik, thanks. Haven't tried that yet. I've fiddled with it and the timeline and activity list features do look promising, but how would I go about assigning a number of contacts to such a project that is flexible enough, i.e. can change in size and type of contacts during project execution? And how would I create an overview list of these contacts?

Comment: You could possibly use the case roles for that? For example you have a number of journalists for a specific project. You would add a case role 'Journalist' and attach the related journalists to the case?